# Collapse button don't work in different tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 different tabs (that only change the order of the posts), and each have a list of collapse buttons, however, they only work in the first tab, on the other tabs the button don't "open". How can I fix this problem?

Here is my collapse button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default stat-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="<%= " #collapse_#{improvement_action.id}" %>
    ">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Comments (<%= improvement_action.comments.count %>)
</button>

<div id='<%= "collapse_#{improvement_action.id}" %>' class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="post-footer">

            COLLAPSED TEXT

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here are my tabs:

```
<div id="tabs-container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1">Active</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Oldest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3">Votes</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
        TAB 1

    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
        TAB 2
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
        TAB 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript for the tabs:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Here is an example of what happens (but in my case the button will have to be the same, so I can't create two different buttons with different id's):

http://jsfiddle.net/xuh9xt7o/

EDIT:

Source example:

```
 <!-- TAB HERE -->

    <div id="tabs-container" >
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1">Recent</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Votes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3">Oldest</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
        <p> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <div class="row">



      <div class="panel panel-white post panel">
        <div class="post-heading">
          <div class="pull-left image">
            <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" class="img-circle avatar" alt="user profile image">
          </div>
          <div class="pull-left meta">
            <div class="title h5">
              <b> joao@mail.com </b>
            </div>
            <h6 class="text-muted time"> about 6 hours </h6>    </h6>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="post-description">
          <p>  agree!!</p>
          <div class="stats">

               <!-- unsign_in user! -->
                    <a class="btn btn-default stat-item" rel="nofollow" data-method="put" href="/improvement_actions/32/like">
                        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span > 2</span>
    </a>                <a class="btn btn-default stat-item" rel="nofollow" data-method="put" href="/improvement_actions/32/like">
                        <span class="fa fa-thumbs-up icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span > 2</span>
    </a>


    <!-- COLLAPSE BUTTON HERE!! -->

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default stat-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse_32">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Comments (0)
                </button>

            <div id='collapse_32' class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="post-footer">



                      <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/comments.self-b85a9aba9d1b331db3d95dbde7deb0beb400c786249465d5ad4824c6b77d0240.css?body=1" />


        <form class="new_comment" id="new_comment" action="/improvement_actions/32/comments" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="9ugV0/I9M1tC2lDJEiNnaVGBFK0flYQ9VuLbfmBJfacQ0eunlp+uItmzIwAskRgVOlgytFNvxIeLnoPnyobqng==" />



            <div class="input-group">
              <input placeholder="Add a comment" class="form-control" type="text" name="comment[body]" id="comment_body" />
              <div class="input-group-addon">
        <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default1">
                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
    </button>  </div>
            </div>


    </form>




                      <br>
                      <h4>0 Comments  </h4>





                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>








                </div>



                </div>



                </div>

      <hr>

                </div>
```

Comment: can you create a demo with your problem in it?

Comment: i updated my question with an example of what happens

Answer (score 0):

You have two divs with the same id of demo. When you click the second button it is affecting the first one it encounters in the DOM (which is in the first tab)

EDIT (more info): Change the data-target to something like demo2 and the collapsible content from demo to demo2 and it will work

Comment: the demo was just to show what is happening, my problem is that it's the same button, but appearing in different order on the tabs

Comment: In that case, you would have to change the data-target attribute based on the current tab. Would need to see a demo more like the exact problem you're facing to offer specific advice.

Comment: i cant put it on jsfiddle because my code have partials and ruby

Comment: Are your tabs from Bootstrap, another framework, or custom?

Comment: they are custom, but I can change if it's easier. they are based on this ones http://jsfiddle.net/syahrasi/us8uc/

Comment: Is there any way you can load the page locally, view source (once the Ruby has rendered) and post that as example code?  

If not, basically you want to add a handler for each tab (either based on visibility or the click of the tab itself that shows the content) and change the data-target attribute of the button to match the id of the collapsible inside that tab.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear what the problem is since that only has one collapsible  and it's id matches the data-target of the button. The button is also contained in the tab so it's not clear why it needs to have the same attributes each time it's output.

Comment: I think the problem its like the first demo I showed, the button have the same ID in the different tabs

Comment: it's the same on both tabs: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default stat-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse_32">`

Comment: The 'proper' way to handle it would be for the href (in this case #collapse_32) to match the collapsible id. If you're creating it dynamically, and rendering it each time you render a tab, I don't see why the href of the button can't change too. This would also make it semantically correct HTML since each id attribute is supposed to be unique.

Comment: do you know how can I do that ?

Comment: Use the same Ruby snippet that gives the id to the collapsibe. Theoretically it's in some sort of a loop, since your outputting multiple tabs, so the same code outputting the tab id should be able to go right into the href portion of the button (after the #).

Comment: but I need also the "#collapse_32", so what would be the href with also the id tab

Comment: Doesn't your code generate that id/href too? If you're using back-end code to create your HTML, it should be handling all of the dynamic things. The code that creates the tab and generates it's content remains where it is now and you re-use a snippet from that Ruby to generate the button above it.

Answer (score 0):

`id`s have to be unique, if you change the `id` of the collapse `div` in tab 2, it should work:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">
    simple collapsible
</button>

<div id="demo1" class="collapse fade">
    <div class="well">Content here</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xuh9xt7o/2/ updated js

Comment: my example was on very good, because it was just to show the problem. in my case it's just a button. so I can't create to buttons with different id's